# How to open system dialog in windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I would like to open system dialog from my app. Is it possible? I mean that a user presses button and my app will open a specific dialog (e.g. wi-fi setting or another dialog in Settings).

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use [URI schemes for launching built-in apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), hence WP8.1 has backward compatibility, the presnted methods will work - for example to open *Bluetooth* use:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-bluetooth:"));
```